# Fractional fields of integral domains

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory

The question is:

> Let $R$ be an integral domain, and $K(R)(\neq R)$ be the fractional
>   field of $R$. Prove that any non-zero $K(R)$-vector space cannot be a
>   free $R$-module.

Can anybody give a sketch of the proof? What method should I go by to prove this? I'm unable to begin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** In a free $R$-module, if $v$ is among the generators and $r$ is not a unit, then there is no element $u$ such that $ru=v$.

Comment: I'll use that to proceed with. Thanks